# Issue using Surf, X Y Z and C cannot be complex

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to add a title to my surface plot, but attempting to add any descriptive text to the plot results in the above error. I can plot the data just fine, but attempting to add the title throws the error. I've listed my code below and can't figure out why a simple text title causes problems. I'd appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

```
function LWMMSweepPlots(excel,cpb,rpb)
    data=xlsread(excel);
    [r,c]=size(data);
    iterations=round(c./cpb);
    for i=1:iterations;
        power=data(1:rpb,cpb*(i-1)+1:cpb*(i-1)+cpb);
        xone=data(rpb*4-3:rpb*4-3+(rpb-1),cpb*(i-1)+1:cpb*(i-1)+cpb);
        yone=data(rpb*5-2:rpb*5-2+(rpb-1),cpb*(i-1)+1:cpb*(i-1)+cpb);
        xtwo=data(rpb+2,cpb*(i-1)+1);
        ytwo=data(rpb*2+3,cpb*(i-1)+1);
        xtn=num2str(xtwo);ytn=num2str(ytwo);
        mytitle=strcat('X2,Y2 Coordinates:',xtn,',',ytn);
        figure;surf(xone,yone,power,title(mytitle))
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you add a title. If you want to add a title you need to use `title` *separately*. They way that you are doing it, MATLAB is treating the *output of `title`* as the `CData` of the surface.

```
figure
surf(xone, yone, power)
title(mytitle)
```